# NGINX url rewrite on digitalocean

Tags: nginx

I have problem with url rewrite from example.com to www.example.com on nginx web server. I using new hosting digitalocean.com and still struggling with this...

I will be happy with every opinion.

There is my code:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.com;

  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;        
  }
}
```

I have error when I trying to restart nginx server:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should 
increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: you didn't explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: sry already edited Thanks!

Comment: First server block is duplicated, is this how you really have it ?

Comment: Sry there was typo... This is same like in my nginx server with same error notice.

Comment: I think the problem is not here, is your real server name long?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean "Real server name long ?"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43336/discussion-between-makromat-and-mohammad-abushady)

Answer (score 2):

The server name is probably too long for the default values.

Modify the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file by adding the following below the http:

```
increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
```

Save this value and test using the -t

```
nginx -t
```

Also, watch for any saved default configurations in the sites-available folder which may cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.com;

  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;        
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd say it should be `301` not `302`

Comment: hey Mohammad I have already edited code... I have error during restart nginx server. Do you know why ?